# aggregating data during convert vertical data into horizontal data( like R's dcast function)

Tags: python, sum, dcast

**Input:**

```
x   y   z   a     b     wkn   year   S1   S2
A   1   6   121   1066  18    2015   10   5
A   1   6   121   1066  18    2015   20   6
A   1   6   121   1066  19    2015   5    3
```

**Expected output:**

```
x   y   z    a      b   wkn   S1_2015  S2_2015
A   1   6   121   1066  18      30      11
A   1   6   121   1066  19      5       3
```

group_keys=[x,y,z,a,b,wkn]

aggrgated_function: sum

can anyone help me to get the expected output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is in `pandas.DataFrame`, you can simply do:

```
df.groupby(['x','y','z','a','b','wkn','year]).agg('sum')
```

which will result:

```
                                    S1  S2
x   y   z   a   b    wkn    year        
A   1   6   121 1066  18    2015    30  11
                      19    2015    5   3
```

Comment: Okay, but i need suffix as year, if i am having more than one year then it has to be create s1 and s2 for both the years separately based on group keys.